# req.session is undefined when deploy Heroku, assumption it fails to connect with Amazon RDS MySQL

Tags: node.js, session, heroku, nuxt.js, express-session

I am working on Nuxt.js app. When using express-session and express-mysql-session, the server middleware always throw the error that req.session is undefined. This problem doesn't exist when I run on my localhost, but when deployed to Heroku. If anyone know how to solve, please don't leave me with this problem forever. Thank you. If you need to see any part of my code let me know. I want to connect Heroku with Amazon RDS MySQL. I found that the express-mysql-session maybe fails to connect with the database since it doesn't create sessions table on the database.

```
//app.js
const config = require('config');

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const logger = require('./lib/logger');
const helmet = require('helmet'); // Security

const { mainPool, mysql } = require('./db-connection');

global._ = require('underscore');

const app = express();

logger.debug("Overriding 'Express' logger");
app.use(require('morgan')('combined', { stream: logger.stream }));

app.use(express.json({ limit: config.test.requests.maximum }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(helmet({
  hsts: false // Temp patch to perhaps allow non-SSL during testing  TODO   REMOVE WHEN SSL AVAILABLE
}));

app.use(cookieParser());

var session = require('express-session');
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
var sessionStore = new MySQLStore({}/* session store options */, mainPool);

app.use(session({
  // How frequently expired sessions will be cleared; milliseconds:
  checkExpirationInterval: config.test.sessions.checkExpirationInterval,
  // The maximum age of a valid session; milliseconds:
  expiration: config.tests.sessions.expiration,
  // Whether or not to create the sessions database table, if one does not already exist:
  createDatabaseTable: true,
  // Number of connections when creating a connection pool:
  connectionLimit: 1,
  key: config.test.sessions.key,
  secret: config.test.sessions.secret,
  store: sessionStore,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

module.exports = app;
```

```
// index.js
const app = require('./app.js');
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')

// const app = express();
// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

async function start () {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  await nuxt.ready()
  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

```
\\ db-connection
var mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const logger = require('./lib/logger');

var mainPool;

const config = require('config');

logger.info('Creating MySQL connection pool, connectionLimit:', config.test.dbconfig.mainDatabase.connectionLimit);

// MySQL connection pools
mainPool = mysql.createPool(config.test.dbconfig.mainDatabase);

module.exports.mainPool = mainPool;
module.exports.mysql = mysql;
```

```
// config.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  test: {
    dbconfig: {
      mainDatabase: {
        host: 'host.rds.amazonaws.com',
        user: 'username',
        password: 'pwd',
        database: 'dbmane',
        connectionLimit: 3,
        ssl: {
          ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem'))
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you properly configured MySQL setup on heroku? If so then do the library created table for you or not if not then it maybe connection problem o the library.

Comment: You're right, it cannot create session table in the db. I followed the instruction [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds) to configure the Heroku.

Comment: Then you can answer your own question if the problem solved :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is it is still cannot access to the database. There might be something wrong. Do you know a way to config the Heroku and Nuxt.js setup to work with express-mysql-session.

Comment: @PanupongLeenawarat did you find answer?